# SQL ORDER BY Function

Tags: mysqli

```js
SELECT start FROM scheduling 
WHERE residentid='2'
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(start,'%H:%i:%s') desc;
   ------- start is type VARCHAR(10)--------------

'02:19PM'
'9:25PM'
'4:45PM'
NULL
'02:19PM'
''
'02:25AM'
```

I don't understand why my dates aren't being ordered correctly, I made everything as per what I found, but I still cant get the start times to be in descending order. If you see there is a 9:25PM then there is a 4:45PM., but that does not make sense, since 9:35PM comes after 4:45PM but also I treid asc,(ascending) still does not work

Comment: Please do not post code (which includes SQL) in an image. It can't be copied and pasted, it's difficult to read, and it's text already in your editor so you're doing more work to screenshot it and upload it than you would with a simple copy/paste.. Post it as text in your question. It also helps if you include the data type of your columns (the DDL that created the table).

Comment: Alright Will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *  FROM scheduling
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(REPLACE(start, 'AM', ' AM'), 'PM', ' PM'),'%l:%i %p') desc;
```

Updated answer.

[sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f49d7b/18/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f49d7b/18/0)

Comment: No it doesn't work, it simply shows one long column of "NULL"

Comment: Sorry but it's stills how a single column of all "NULL"

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63ed6/1

Can you set up an example with some of your data?  Makes it easier for us to try out some things.

Comment: The funny thing is whenever I put my data, in a SQL website like sqlfiddle, it works fine, all of yours, works fine, but in the mySQL workbench, it doesnt, i will try tho....

Comment: I am trying to make an example table with some values I will paste the fiddle here when I sucessfully make it...

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: I got it to reproduce at this link......http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdd81/2

Comment: Why do you want the %s parameter when you don't even have seconds in your input???

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE(start, "%H,%i") as start FROM scheduling
ORDER BY start desc; Doestn work

Comment: Hmm it does work with that data, but it still does not work with my data, i still get a long list of "NULL" values

Comment: Add some of your data, it's probably strangely formatted times, like the AM and PM without space between it

Comment: I made a link of data that I exported from my table.   https://anonfile.com/T2p8L0eabf/datta.csv

Comment: Don't know why but it seems to work fine for me: 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f49d7b/18/0

Comment: I guess it does, I apparently dont need this anymore, hugh *too many hours spent on it* ill mark your answer as right

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM scheduling 
WHERE residentid='2'
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(start,'%H:%i:%s') desc;
```

Comment: I assumed start was a datetime field. You know what they say about assume , right?

Comment: No it's a VARCHAR(10)